# Retrieving a value from pascals triangle

Tags: arrays, combinations, pascals-triangle

I have a one dimensional array that is holding values of pascal's triangle counting the numbers from left to right.

```
int pascal[10] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1 };
```

How can I use this to quickly find the combination of two numbers?

e.g. to find 3 choose 1, I would look in the array to find the answer 3. How can I correctly calculate the index that I need to look at?

If I wanted to continue building Pascal's triangle, how can I use this array to build it without doing tree recursion? Something like a recurrence relation

Comment: Do you have to use an array? Surely it's quicker to use `C(n,k)=(n!)/((k!)(n-k)!)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using the array rather than calculating it via formula then you can use following (C# example):

```
int Choose_N_over_K(int N, int K)
{
    int[] pascal  = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 3, 3, 1, 1,4,6,4,1};    
    var index = (N * (N + 1) / 2 +  K  );
    return (pascal[index]);
}


void Main()
{
        Console.WriteLine(Choose_N_over_K(4,2));
}
```

Giving (for the example of 4 over 2):

```
6
```

We simply calculate the index in the array based on the fact that every row in triangle has one more element than the previous row *and* we know how to sum numbers `1..N`:

```
// 0: 1  start index 0
// 1: 1 1  start index 1
// 2: 1 2 1  start index 3 
// 3: 1 3 3 1 start index 6
// 4: 1 4 6 4 1 start index 10
```

Comment: showing the diagram at the bottom made it really clear for me. Thanks a bunch!